# Is possible to use JDBC to connect MS Access to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, jdbc, jtds

I already do the connection using ODBC, but I'm having some slowness issues, I find out the jTDS, they say that is the fastest JDBC, so I'm trying to use it in my project, but without sucess, someone know how to use jTDS to connect MS Access Front-End to SQL Server Back-end?

Here's my code using ODBC, it is inside a loop:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase _
            acLink, _
            "ODBC Database", _
            "ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & vIP & ";Database=" & vDb & "; UID=" & vUser & "; PWD=" & vPwd & "; ", _
            acTable, _
            rstSchema!table_name, _
            rstSchema!table_name, , True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: **NO** You can not use JDBC driver for MSSQL frontend.

Long Answer: 
JDBC driver enables java based application connect to SQL Server. So for different databases different JDBC drivers are available.

Unfortunately JDBC having different requirements and will not fit in stack what you are using. For MS Access Frontend ODBC is a natural choice.

You can think of consuming microservices. But this will be overkill for MS Access front end.

Instead think of how you can tune queries or can use some server side cursor / procedures depend on your scenario.

Comment: Good advice, especially re: looking at the front-end application for ways to make it work better with ODBC linked tables. I suspect that it might be *possible* to use an ODBC-JDBC bridge to enable linked tables that use jTDS instead of mssql-odbc, but that extra layer of complexity (and, most likely, cost) would probably not offer any significant improvement in performance.

Comment: Thanks! I have these three options of drivers _SQL Server_, _ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server_, _SQL Server Native Client 11.0_, all of then are slowest than the MS Access database, you have any idea of a driver that is faster than these three?

Comment: @Fritsch, ODBC Diver 13.1 for SQL Server is the latest ODBC driver. I have used it to retrieve over 1M rows per second from SQL Server, albeit not via Access linked tables. What sort over performance are you seeing?

Comment: To load data isn't slow, but some codes are, like the `.Requery`, you know why? @DanGuzman

Comment: @Fritsch, not knowing much about Access, I don't know how ReQuery interacts with SQL Server. You could run an ODBC trace on the client or a backend SQL trace (Profiler or Extended Events) to see what SQL is actually being sent. It could be some index tuning is needed. Or it might be for some other reasons, like a slow network or one with high latency.

Comment: I created a SQL Profiler, and the requery only do a Select, I notice the linked tables in my project are just "tblName", in the Select it writes "dbo"."tblName", do you think this can be a problem? Just a disclaimer, isn't network problem